# How to make one BigInteger from a 4 byte number

Tags: java

The essence of the task is this, I encode the bytes of the file, 1 byte of the source file = 4 bytes of the encrypted one. For example, the encoded byte is 3125890409. In byte representation, this is [186, 81, 77, 105]. For decryption, I must present this array as a single number. How can I first convert these 4 numbers to binary, and then to decimal and assign BigIntger? I thought to do it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < fileData2.length; i+=4) {
    BigInteger message = BigInteger.valueOf(fileData2[i]);
    BigInteger message2 = BigInteger.valueOf(fileData2[i + 1]);
    BigInteger message3 = BigInteger.valueOf(fileData2[i + 2]);
    BigInteger message4 = BigInteger.valueOf(fileData2[i + 3]);
}
```

And then translate each into binary, but it looks too complicated, and what if you need to do not 4 bytes, but 8 bytes and higher. How can it be implemented faster?

Comment: 4 bytes is an `int`, which you could simply pack in a loop via `myInt = (myInt << 8) | nextByte`.

Comment: "1 byte of the source file = 4 bytes of the encrypted one. For example, the encoded byte is 3125890409" That does not make sense in a number of ways. First, how is "3125890409" a single byte? And second, are you *encoding* or *encrypting*? Those are very different things.

Comment: I agree encoding and encryption are two different things - the OP has a function that converts 8 bits->32bits, wants to write a reverse function and is wondering how to deal with the bytes obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Do not bother with BigInteger or BigDecimals. Instead think of your original byte as one byte (or 8 bits), and the encoded/encrypted values as 4 bytes (32 bits). If you just shove them into a byte[] you can choose an arbitrary size - be it 4, 8, or 13. Lots of flexibility there.

This approach makes it also easier to read/write the data, as you might simply serialize the bytes into a stream//read the data from a stream, as it feels quite natural to read and write the low indexes of the array first.

Once done with that, all you have to focus on is your function to turn 8 bits into 32 bits and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

4 bytes fit in an `int`. Though a negative one here. Use a long otherwise. The byte order seems to be *big endian*, most significant byte first - it is an odd number as is the last byte.

```
byte[] fileData = {(byte)186, 81, 77, 105};
int n = new BigInteger(fileData).intValue();
int n = ByteBuffer.wrap(fileData).byteOrder(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getInt();
long nn = n & 0xFF_FF_FF_FFL;
```

BIG_ENDIAN is the default, so the byteOrder is not needed here.